# What is __MvcPagesVersion__ for in Visual Studio project file?

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, mono, monodevelop

I created an MVC/Web API project in VS 2013.  When I try to open that solution with Monodevelop, it fails with error "There must be 2, 3 or 4 components in the version string.". It's because of the references in .csproj file such as `<Reference Include="System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=__MvcPagesVersion__, ..."> ... </Reference>`.

How can I fix those references so that it can be compiled with Monodevelop? Is it safe just to remove Version string from those references?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ran into a similar problem just now.  `__MvcPagesVersion__` must be some placeholder Visual Studio uses in the *.csproj files.  I combed through the csproj file that wouldn't load in Xamarin Studio and replaced all the references to `__MvcPagesVersion__` with "5.2.0.0" without the quotes.  I then reloaded the project and everything seems to be working for me now.

Comment: I managed to compile it using the same method, just putting "5.2.0" (or similar, don't remember now) instead :)